# Do seeds get frozen and unusable, if held in a cold garage over winter?

Tags: seed-saving

I collected some seeds this year, and I meant to store them in a garage that gets cold in winter (temperatures are approximately the same as outdoors temperatures). However, an aquientance says they will be frozen, and not viable anymore next spring. I told her, what about natural processes, she says it is different, seeds are on the ground, there is snow, etc.

Is she right?

Comment: Plants have manage to survive OK for millions of years before humans invented heated houses. A *native* species isn't going to die if it is kept at "outdoors" temperatures. In fact, some seeds won't germinate at all *unless* they have been frozen over winter - the plants have evolved so the seeds won't start germinating *before* winter, but wait till the next spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not true that if seeds freeze they will no longer be viable  - seedbanks round the world freeze seeds for long term storage. The difficulty is temperature fluctuation and humidity - a sudden bout of warmer weather with high humidity is more likely to ruin the seeds if they are stored in your garage. If you've room  in your freezer  at the back, that's  probably the best way to store them, inside ziplock bags, well wrapped, more info on that here https://underwoodgardens.com/seed-saving-and-storage/

Comment: I've stored daylily and North American native plant seeds in a detached garage off and on over the years in Wisconsin, and until recently have had only one problem - mice (they ate all of the daylily seeds, and many of the natives). But that was before 2010. Things have changed in my area since then, and we no longer are as severely cold and snowy. We've had rain and thunderstorms in January in 2017 and 2018, which was totally unheard of just a few years ago. Now, I get 6-10 weeks of cold in the garage (December & January) and then put the seeds in a fridge for a few weeks before planting.

Comment: Because of the afore-mentioned mouse issue, I use only covered glass containers to store the seeds.